# SoftLayer API how to filter MetricDataTypes

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Can I filter metric data types?

I am retrieving datatypes with keynames CPU0, CPU1, etc up to CPU256, plus some other datatypes.  I would like a filter to retrieve only the datatypes that do not start with CPU.  I tried the filter below but all objects were still retrieved:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/<objectId>/getMetricDataTypes?objectFilter=objectFilter=objectFilter={"metricDataTypes":{"keyName":{"operation":"!*= CPU"}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to filter **MetricDataTypes**, because this datatype: [SoftLayer_Container_Metric_Data_Type](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/getMetricDataTypes) doesn't have any relation property like id

I recommend to use a programming language and filter in the code, to see programming languages supported by SoftLayer:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/