# Getting RC 500 using objectFilter in users field openIdConnectUserName

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to retrieve a user profile by openIdConnectUserName.

The URL is:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers.json?objectMask=mask[virtualGuestCount,virtualGuests.id,virtualGuests.hostname,virtualGuests.status,hardwareCount,hardware.id,hardware.hostname,hardware.hardwareStatus,userStatus,apiAuthenticationKeyCount,apiAuthenticationKeys,loginAttemptCount,successfulLoginCount,unsuccessfulLoginCount]&objectFilter={"users":{"openIdConnectUserName":{"operation":"thisguy@us.ibm.com"}}}
```

I am getting RC 500 with message of "Internal Server Error"

Is this a valid objectFilter field?

Answer (score 0):

Attempt the query without the objectFilter.  If it works, you will know it is an invalid objectFilter.

It is also possible you are querying too much data.  If a query result is too large, it can return a 500 error.  You can try the limit/offset parameters.  This seems unlikely since you are filtering on a specific email address.

Comment: I used the http request specified without the limits.  The number of user profiles returned were 708  I don't think the objectFilter is working correctly.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

The error you are getting is probably due to that the response is way to big, for this reason you should use result limits (see links at the bottom).

But the main problem is because the object filter is not working properly, the reason may be due that main datatype containing openIdConnectUserName property does not have any relational property, see below for a brief explanation when this kind of issues occurs:

*"Unfortunately, it's not possible to **Filter** MetricDataTypes, because this datatype: SoftLayer_Container_Metric_Data_Type doesn't have any relation property ..."*- 
[SoftLayer API how to filter MetricDataTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42146029/softlayer-api-how-to-filter-metricdatatypes)

As a workaround I would recommend to use another property like "email" with "managedByOpenIdConnectFlag" (which as "true" determines if this portal user is managed by IBMid federation, and email should be the same as openIdConnectUserName) added to the object mask and then use them with object filters.

Or you may use a programming language to filter by the specific property you required (openIdConnectUserName) as forum provided recommends.

P.D.: I noticed that the request you provided doesn´t have the "openIdConnectUserName" property inside the object mask for example, therefore the response would not deliver this property even of it`s properly defined in the filter, when using object filters it is required that property needed in the response, should be declared in the object mask previously.

Fore more information please see below:

[solve error fetching http headers](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/how-solve-error-fetching-http-headers)

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/using-result-limits-softlayer-api